# Svelte does not update value in one if branch

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to implement some currency input in Svelte.

Almost everything works as excepted, but if I remove the input in the field with `Backspace`, I can see the log message, but the value is not set to `'0.00'`.

I have prepared a REPL for this: https://svelte.dev/repl/2b83934eff9747a1a1c7a15c976be316?version=3.31.2

```
<script>
  let amountFormatted = '0.00';
  let currencyInput;
 
  $: console.log('amountFormatted: ' + amountFormatted);

   const handleChange = () => {
     console.log('currentInput: ' + currencyInput.value);

     let cleanedInput = currencyInput.value
      .replace(/\D*/gm, '') // remove non digits
      .replace(/^0+/gm, ''); // remove leading zeros 
     console.log('cleanedInput.length: ' + cleanedInput.length);

    if (cleanedInput.length === 0 ) {
      console.log('setting amountFormatted to 0.00 --- BUT IT does not work ');
      amountFormatted = '0.00'; // ERROR this never works
    } else {
      amountFormatted = (parseInt(cleanedInput, 10) / 100).toString();
    }
  };
</script>

<input
    type="tel"
    value={amountFormatted}
    bind:this={currencyInput}
    on:input={handleChange}
/>
```

I almost spend the whole day to get this working as wanted. I tried things like `tick()` and a lot of other stuff, but it seems that `amountFormatted = '0.00';` never triggers a reactive change.

Comment: `currencyInput.value = '0.00';` doing this works

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you very much. But I am still curious why the other approach does not work! But I want to thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is doing with `bind` works

```
<input
    type="tel"
    bind:value={amountFormatted} // Not sure why without bind is not working, need to explore
    bind:this={currencyInput}
    on:input={handleChange}
/>
```

Or Second:

```
   if (cleanedInput.length === 0 ) {
      console.log('setting amountFormatted to 0.00 --- BUT IT does not work ');
      currencyInput.value = '0.00'; // this works
    } else {
      amountFormatted = (parseInt(cleanedInput, 10) / 100).toString();
    }

<input
    type="tel"
    value={amountFormatted}
    bind:this={currencyInput}
    on:input={handleChange}
/>
```

As per [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/numeric-inputs) I understood that for `numeric inputs`,

```
value={somevaribale} is one way binding

bind:value={somevaribale} is two way binding.
```

Comment: Without `bind` input value is not updating, need to check on that.

Comment: Let me know if you figured out why it's behaving like this

Comment: I will if I know. But since today is my first day with Svelte, I can't promise to find the solution ;)

Comment: Yeah, Im also new to this, but figured it out, It's binding issue, updated my answer, Check the REPL

Comment: Not sure. Because in the else branch it worked. Even without `bind:value.`

Comment: yeah, I've observed that too, strange!!

Answer (score 1):

In case some is interested for an answer one year later:

Entering the if-block several times in a row won't trigger an update for amountFormatted because the value hasn't changed. It is already 0.00 from the previous call. You can test it by adding `amountFormatted = 'foo'` one line before to force an update.